# How to load a component once & just change data within it to re-render html?

Tags: angular, typescript

Well I have a scenario where my navigation panel has multiple pages & on clicking of let's say contact us, Contact Us Component is loaded, it's ngOnInit runs.

Now user switches to another webpage by clicking "Our products", now Our products component is laoded.

Now when user clicks again on Contact Us link, my Contact Us component gets reinitialized( because ngOnInit runs again). But i want that it should just show the previous component's html.

PS: Navigation panel has switchCase in which every component is called. So on clicking on one panel, that component runs.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./test-common.css"],
  })

  export class DummyComponent{ 

  @Input('nameOfSection')name = 'Home'; 

  changeName() {
    this.name = "duck";
  }
}
```

HTML code where this component is called is like :

```
<div ngSwitch> 
<example ngSwitchCase> </example>
</div>
```

So whenever this switch case is executed, the component is initialized. I want that somehow i can reuse the once initialized component.

This component is an example. I need that when switch case runs for first time, this component should be loaded.
But on further runs, the already loaded component should be re-used.

Comment: Why would you like to have persistent components as opposed to transient ones? Is it because you think loading a component each time is slower and leads to laggy experience on end-user's side?

Comment: One way would be to load all the components when the navigation panel is opened and keep them hidden. And toggle their visibility using either CSS animation or Angular animation.

Comment: Well yes. IMO loading a component is a slow process.

Comment: For your 2nd option : My components are called inside a switch case. So when ever the switch case is called it will load the component called inside it. So css is not helpful here.